# Android - how to add view to LinearLayout with RecylcerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a list of items. Each row has a TextView title and a LinearLayout containing child views. Eg:

+++++++++++++++++++++++

Title 1

Child_1: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

Child_2: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

Child_3: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

+++++++++++++++++++++++

Title 2

Child_1: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

Child_2: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

Child_3: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

+++++++++++++++++++++++

**The problem I'm facing is that the LinearLayout is not showing all the child view. Its only showing child_1 and its prices, but not child_2 and child_3.**

+++++++++++++++++++++++

Title 1

Child_1: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

+++++++++++++++++++++++

Title 2

Child_1: price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 price_5

+++++++++++++++++++++++

layout_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

item_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/child_text_view"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/flowLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/child_text_view"
            f:debugDraw="true"
            f:layoutDirection="ltr"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private MyViewHolder mMyViewHolder;
    private MyObj mMyObj;

    @Override
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) { }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)  { }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) { }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView mTitleTextView;
        protected LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
            mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_linear_layout);
        }
    }

    @Override     
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {     
        if (viewHolder instanceof MyViewHolder) {     
            mMyViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;     
            mMyObj = (MyObj) mItems.get(i);     
            mMyViewHolder.mTitleTextView.setText(     mMyObj.getTitle());
            mMyViewHolder.mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();     
            for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MyObj2>> entry : mMyObj.getNewMap().entrySet()) {     
                mMyViewHolder.mLinearLayout.addView(makeChildView(entry));     
            }     
        } else if () { }     
    }

    private View makeChildView(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MyObj2>> entry) {
        // Inflate child text view and price
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my question. Well I needed to add android:orientation="vertical" to the root LinearLayout in layout_main.xml. It took me a while because the same layout works when I used it without RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"> // This line fix it

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```